# Cucumber test pass fail report is wrong

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, cucumber, gherkin

Though the actual result of test should be fail, cucumber shows as pass. Another issue is it does not execute all feature files. It runs tests within only one folder and never stops last test case execution and never runs next folder test cases.

I am using java 1.8 for this project.
This is Run.java file.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/resources"
)

public class Run {
}
```

inside resources folder it has two sub folders which contains all feature files.
I tried with below option.
Delete cache in intelliJ idea and restarting it.
Have anyone experienced this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the folder/files structure as well as the package names?

Comment: Okay. This is a maven project. So project files are in "src" folder. There are two folders inside "src" folder as "resources" and "java". Inside "java" folder, It has Run.java file.  There is another sub folder inside "java" which keeps step definitions.
Inside "resources" folder, I kept two sub folders as "first" and "second". Inside these sub folders, I kept list of feature files.

Answer (score 0):

First, add your feature files (let say: **Example.feature**) in a specific folder (let say: features) under the *resource* folder

Second, add a step definition file for the feature file under a folder name **stepDef**

Then add these two lines under CucumberOptions:

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/main/resources/features/Example.feature",
    glue = "xyz.abc.<path to your step def. folder>.stepDef",)
```

Try to run this class.

Also, refer to this documentation as well [Cucumber Reference](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/)